# Lacie Porsche not working on MBP 15"

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

I've bought a [Lacie Porsche usb key](http://www.lacie.com/LU/products/product.htm?id=10617) two weeks ago and it used to work well but now I can't mount it on my MBP, it's not even detected by the system profiler... But it works well on a friend MBA or even worse, on a Windows computer...

My USB ports works well with other devices like HDD or some usb key of other brands. Any tips ?

Comment: Use Disk Utility to see it there?

Comment: @Buscar웃 nop, the device is not shown on the left panel.

Comment: Format the USB device to exFat for example and try to mount it again.